# How to Link another page, at a certain point HTML

Tags: html

So I want the button to link to page 2 at a certain height, like Wikipedia
I've tried linking it but it doesn't seem to do anything

```
<div class="button1">
<button><a id="#areas.html#location1"></a>Button1</button></div>
```

CSS

```
.button1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28%;
  left: 22.2%;
}
```

Page 2

Comment: you probably just need it like: <a href="areas.html#location1"></a>

Comment: posted a working answer. have a look. You can add href to another page in button as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after some trial and error and using the comments I think I fixed it allowing it to use the  tag (also removed the hyperlink underline and color)
Credit for helping goes to Raptor & AlwaysHelping

This is linking button

```
<button> <a href="filename.html#locationlink1" style="text-decoration: none;">Button words</a></button>
```

This is the target div

```
<div id="locationlink1"></div>
```

And the CSS for color changing the hyperlink color to black

```
a
{
color: #000000;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need.

Just use a button with link to another page then `div` or `a` and give it `name="location1"` to go direct to that section of the page.

Button to another page

```
<button onclick="location.href='areas.html#location1'" type="button">Button1</button>
```

If your `area.html` file

```
<div name="location1">
  content
</div>
```

Comment: It works, except JS is disabled. That's why Web Designers prefer to use `<a>` tag and style the hyperlink to look like a button.

Comment: @Raptor i prefer to `<a>` as well but i am guessing the person likes to have button click.

Comment: The second part of your answer is incorrect. You should use an anchor `<a name="location1">` instead of an `id`

Comment: @Raptor Agree to that. That's a typo. Thanks Though.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I've tried to run this but it only takes me to the page as if I was using a normal href linking `<div class="button1">
    <button> <a name="area.html#location1"> Button1</a></button>
    </div>` and the CSS `<div name="location1">
        content
      </div>`

Comment: @Dakotah Hutchinson I am not sure why you are using ‘a’ tag in button. Either you can use a tag or button dont use together. Copy the exact code I have mentioned above and it’s should all good. Let me know.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping The issue is that it only links to the page, It doesn't specifically link to an area on the page, Same as using the <a> tag.